# using setTimeout vs comparing timestamp on an update loop

Tags: javascript, performance, time

With Javascript, in an application that uses an update function that runs for every rendered frame and seeks every minutest optimization:

If one wants to run code every so often and the precision of time is mostly unimportant, is there a wise choice between using a `setTimeout` loop or just building a timer into the update function of the application?

For instance, does `setTimeout` have some unexpected computational cost that makes it clearly slower? Or, on the other hand, would `setTimeout` positively affect the application because Javascript is not in a hurry to make a `setTimeout` callback happen?

Comment: There's only one thread, so using a `while (true)` loop is a very bad idea. On the other hand, `setTimeout` will only execute the callback as soon as the thread is ready - which may be anything from exactly the time you set to `setTimeout`, up to never (if there's `while (true)` loops in your application :)).

Comment: There's no `while(true)`, but there's a monolithic update loop that gets called as often as possible without being called too often; common in games. So I guess the question is whether to check the time in the loop that I already need to run or do it separately with `setTimeout`

Comment: Try this - http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/08/building-a-game-mainloop-in-javascript/. It's a bit old, but it still applies. `setInterval` is a better choice than `setTimeout`, and if the browser supports `window.requestAnimationFrame`, even better. Or http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing. Or just google for "realtime javascript game loop".

Comment: I apologize that I am unclear; the actual application I'm building is already quite mature in its development. Currently, I have an HTML5 application that runs an update function using `requestAnimationFrame`. What I am seeking is some obscure, arcane (perhaps unknown) knowledge about which -- at the very low level -- is quicker between checking for a time difference in my update loop or using a separate setTimeout/setInterval loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timestamp differential is better than a `setTimeout`, but still you need to have the render loop. Therefore you can use the timestamp differential that `requestAnimationFrame` sends as parameter to the callback function.

I hope this answers your question.

Also keep in mind that (as you mentioned), `setTimeout` is postponed to the end of the stack-call. That's why in node.js you have other means of "deferring" functions, and also you have a faster way to compute timestamp differential by using `process.hrtime` instead of having to use `Date` object.

Long answer short would be:

> Use the parameter sent by `requestAnimationFrame` to the callback.